# Spring OAuth2 Authentication object is null with CustomAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring OAuth2 to protect my REST API's and implemented client_credentials, password grant types. They work perfectly fine except ResourceOwnerPassword flow with user credentials in the POST body.

Token endpoint call with the below URL is OK (If we send the user credentials as URL parameters)
HTTP POST: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=123&password=456

But with the below setup, my Authentication.getCredentials and Authentication.getPrincipal Objects are always empty.. I am using a custom authentication provider since I need to validate user against an external LDAP system.

Does this mean user credentials(Usernamd and password) can only be sent in the URL parameters to the token endpoint(/oauth/token)??

My configurations are:

Authorization server configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
      Arrays.asList(new CustomTokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints
    .tokenStore(tokenStore).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
    .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
    .authenticationManager(userAuthenticationManager);
}

 @Bean
AuthenticationManager userAuthenticationManager() {
    List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
    authenticationProviders.add(new CustomAuthenticationProvider()));
    return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
}
```

Custom Authentication provider:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {


    System.out.println("authentication object........"+authentication);
    String userName;
    String password;
    System.out.println("authentication object credentials........"+authentication.getCredentials());
    userName = authentication.getName();
    password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    }
```

Authentication object printed in the console:

org.springframework.security.authentication.Usernam
ePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a2162f9: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]
; Authenticated: false; Details: {grant_type=password}; Not granted any authorities

However, I did find a post where they said user credentials in the request body works with Token endpoint.. Here is the link about it..

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/260

As per the above it seems I am missing something..

Any help/hint would be appreciated..